# Stream Audio from the Microphone to an API in AMR_WB format

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, audiorecord

I need to stream audio from the Microphone to a cloud based API in the `AMR_WB` format which is not currently supported by `AudioRecord` in Android.

This format works with `MediaRecorder`, but that will only save audio to a file.

Is there a way to:

- Extend audio formats supported by `AudioRecord`
- Live stream the data from the file `MediaRecorder` is creating to the cloud
- Encode/Transcode in real time from `AudioRecord` output into a non supported format

Comment: 1)No.   2)Just read the file, then dump the data to your socket.  Should be fairly easy.  3)Real time will depend on the power of the CPU and requirements of the transcoder.  But if you're good enough to write the transcoder and amr_wb works on partial data, sure.

Comment: @GabeSechan If you could point me to an answer for (2), I would be grateful. The cloud API is Google's Speech to Text, and it seems to work in a way that's not compatible with what I see with the answers I've found. It streams into a `ScheduledExecutorService` that consumes a `byte[]` and then is accsessed by a gRPC client in the `MainActivity`.